# Extract data from a JSON file using python

Tags: json, python-3.x, list, parsing, firebase-realtime-database

Say if I have JSON entry as follows(The JSON file generated by fetching data from a Firebase DB):

```
[{"goal_savings": 0.0, "social_id": "", "score": 0, "country": "BR", "photo": "http://graph.facebook", "id": "", "plates": 3, "rcu": null, "name": "", "email": ".", "provider": "facebook", "phone": "", "savings": [], "privacyPolicyAccepted": true, "currentRole": "RoleType.PERSONAL", "empty_lives_date": null, "userId": "", "authentication_token": "-------", "onboard_status": "ONBOARDING_WIZARD", "fcmToken": ----------", "level": 1, "dni": "", "social_token": "", "lives": 10, "bills": [{"date": "2020-12-10", "role": "RoleType.PERSONAL", "name": "Supermercado", "category": "feeding", "periodicity": "PeriodicityType.NONE", "value": 100.0"}], "payments": [], "goals": [], "goalTransactions": [], "incomes": [], "achievements": [{"created_at":", "name": ""}]}]
```

How do I extract the content corresponding to 'value' which is present inside  column 'bills' . Any way to do this ?

My python code is as follows. With this I was only able to get data within bills column. But I need only the entry corresponding to 'value' which is present inside bills.

```
import json
filedata = open('firebase-dataset.json','r')
data = json.load(filedata)
listoffields = []   # To produce it into a list with fields 
for dic in data:
    try:
        listoffields.append(dic['bills'])   # only non-essential bill categories.
    except KeyError:
        pass
print(listoffields)
```

Comment: Your JSON is malformed in several places.

Comment: What do I do for that, In fact I ran fetcher.py to generate the JSON and it generates this file .

Comment: from a firebase db

Comment: Hi, If are you free anytime can we schedule a video call so that I can share my screen and show you the output of my code ?

Comment: Actually I am using poetry to fetch the dataset and convert it as a json file

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you posted contains misplaced quotes.
I think you are trying to  extract the value of 'value' column within bills.

try this

```
print(listoffields[0][0]['value'])
```

which will print you 100.0 as str. use float() to use it in calculations.

*---edit---*
Say the JSON you having contains many JSON objects separated by commas as..

```
[{ first-entry },{ second-entry },{ third.. }, ....and so on]
```

..and you want to find the value of each bill in the each JSON obj..
may be the code below will work.-

```
bill_value_list = []     # to store 'value' of each bill
for bill_list in listoffields:
    bill_value_list.append(float(bill_list[0]['value']))    # blill_list[0]  will contain complete bill dictionary.

print(bill_value_list)    

print(sum(bill_value_list))   # do something usefull
```

Paste it after the code you posted.(*no changes to your code .. since it always works :-)* )

Comment: Okay sure, but then there are many such entries each containing bills. So how do I extract all the bills ? Thanks mahn !

Comment: I hope the edited answer will work for you. you are welcome :-)..